# Send data from Customizer Settings to Customizer Preview with settingless control

Tags: theme-customizer

There are a few ways to speak back and forth with the customizer API. I don't think my scenario is that much f an offshoot so I will give it to you.

1. I have a button in the Customizer to trigger a PHP script. It is a [settingless control](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/03/10/customizer-improvements-in-4-5/) button. The part about it being an action and not a setting is very important. This button only controls an action for the preview pane.
2. The PHP script that the button triggers via AJAX compiles CSS and returns it via the natural `post` javascript functionality.
3. I have no way of pushing the data to a `style` tag in the preview pane so that it changes the look of the site.

I have tried using `partials` but they seem to be hooked to controls with settings. I have tried using `postMessage` but again it seems to be linked to settings. I don't need a setting, I only need a trigger that sends data over.

The point here is that I need an action to take place in PHP with the simple click of a button. I can do it all day in AJAX normally, but transferring data from the Customizer Settings to the Customizer Preview pane with any PHP in the interim is a PAIN. Pun intended.

Comment: So the point is that you need to send PHP retrieved from the customizer panel to preview?